# How to generate Entity with all fields from db table automatically?

Tags: symfony

I am trying to generate Entity from database but it only add id automatically. Is there any console command to automatically generate entity with all fields from db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a console command below to automatically generate setter/getters etc... for an Entity class that you've created:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle/Entity/Product
```

In the above example, the file under 'src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php' would be the Entity class.

Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: I tried this command before I posted here. The problem is, it does not generate all fields, it asks to input new fields except the primary key. Suppose if there are fields in product table ( id, name, description). It only generates id field and ask for others. I want to generate all fields automatically.

Comment: What do you mean "asks for others"? This information you should have put in your original post. Can you show the "exact" commands you used please.

Comment: This command will not import mapping from database, Its a command to generate PHP entity from ORM mapping.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can use `Doctrine reverse engineering` available in Symfony SE. Check the [doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html).

The command will be :

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AcmeBlogBundle xml
```

Where The ORM entities will be imported to `AcmeBlogBundle` with `xml` format. you can change the format of your `ORM` later with annother command. Please check the document for full usage.

Note :

- It's not guranteed, that all your field will be imported. Its all dependent on database mapping.
- All your tables in database will be imported to ORM entities. I didn't see an option to filter one or few tables from database.

Comment: It's possible to filter the tables with this argument: --filter="Yourtablename"

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, long time back though, but didn't work for me. May be I was missing something! Thanks for pointing out.